# Best way to search and show MySQL with friendly URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, url

I have a table in MySQL that looks like this

Table: Students
ID:
Name:
Gender:
Age:

On my website I would like to search the Table by selecting Gender and/or Age.
This part I can do it with a HTML Form and a Select but i would like the output to have the url www.whatever.com/male/16 
And also I would like be able to write www.whatever.com/male or www.whatever.com/18 or www.whatever.com/female/20 and that the output html shows me the SELECT result.

Any idea about how I should approach this or if this is possible? 
Should I make the MySQL into a JSON and then search with JS and modify the URL accordingly, but then I don't know if it's possible to write the URL and then show the desired results, or I should research AJAX...

I would be very grateful with any kind of suggestions.

**EDIT 1**
Maybe I should SELECT everything from the DDBB into an array and do everything else with javascript?
But I don't know how I should do the url part. I mean if I write www.whatever.com/male/16 show me students with those parameters, and if I am in wwww.whatever.com and click a gender to show students with that gender and show in the url www.whatever.com/male

Comment: URL mapping would help you. See this tutorial on URL mapping and MVC on php 
http://www.nathandavison.com/article/10/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-2-url-mapping-and-indexphp

Comment: what kind of webserver do you use?

Comment: Mario It's a typical shared hosting. MySQL, PHP, CPanel… I don't know if that is what you asked for.

Rumesh I'll look into it. Thank you!